# Nested-if in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I follow the real world haskell, and there is an [exercise](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/types-and-functions.html#id581959) in chapter 2.

My solution is

```
lastButOne xs = if null xs || null (tail xs)
                then []
                else if null (tail (tail xs))
                     then head xs
                     else lastButOne (tail xs)
```

but it doesn't work other than [], and produces such an error.

```
*Main> lastButOne []
[]
*Main> lastButOne [1, 2]

<interactive>:5:13:
    No instance for (Num [a0]) arising from the literal `1'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [a0])
    In the expression: 1
    In the first argument of `lastButOne', namely `[1, 2]'
    In the expression: lastButOne [1, 2]
```

I am fairly a newbie and don't understand the cryptic error messages. Any ideas?

Comment: You'll find this much easier to do if you pattern match on the list instead of trying to deconstruct it using `null`, `head` and `tail`.

Comment: does [1,2] really have room for a tail of a tail?

Comment: Lee//Thank you for the suggestion, but I didn't see any mention about pattern matching in chapter 1 and chapter 2. So I don't know about it.

Comment: VoronoiPotato//I think tail (tail [1, 2]) is just []

Answer (score 7):

This is a type problem. If you use GHCi, load this function into it and use

```
:t lastButOne
```

to see its type, which is

```
lastButOne :: [[a]] -> [a]
```

this is because `if` need to have the same type on the then and else branches, and since you are returning a `[]` in the `then` branch, Haskell thinks you are trying to return a list always, and since you are returning `head xs` on the `else` branch, it thinks you are writing a function works on list of lists.

However, `[1, 2]` is not a list of lists, so GHC yelled at you about the type mismatch error.

Also note if you write out the type definition explicitly, it wouldn't compile:

```
lastButOne :: [a] -> a
lastButOne xs = if null xs || null (tail xs)
            then []
            else if null (tail (tail xs))
                 then head xs
                 else lastButOne (tail xs)
```

GHCi gets you an error:

```
Couldn't match type `a' with `[a0]'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for lastButOne :: [a] -> a at k.hs:2:1
In the expression: []
In the expression:
  if null xs || null (tail xs) then
      []
  else
      if null (tail (tail xs)) then head xs else lastButOne (tail xs)
In an equation for `lastButOne':
    lastButOne xs
      = if null xs || null (tail xs) then
            []
        else
            if null (tail (tail xs)) then head xs else lastButOne (tail xs)
```

Comment: Thank you. This answer is just what I wanted. So, [] is interpreted as a list and that was the problem...

Answer (score 1):

`then []` here you return a list.

`then head xs` here you return what's in the list (a number in your case). I'm surprised this compiles at all. You should wrap the result with a `Maybe`, so the result of `lastButOne []` and `lastButOne [x]` should be `Nothing`, and the result of `lastButOne [...,x,_]` should be `Just x`.

Or you could use the `error` pseudofunction in the error case.

Comment: I see. Following Ziyao's answer, the type of the lastButOne is  [[a]]->[a], and it works well for such as lastButOne [[1,2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]. I think, that's the reason why this is compiled successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I think pattern matching is more elegant for this... Being myself a total newbie to Haskell (I just read a little bit about it long ago):

```
lastButOne ([]) = []
lastButOne (beforeLast:last:[]) = beforeLast
lastButOne (x:xs) = lastButOne xs
```

I know that it's not an explanation to your error, but sometimes the best solution is to avoid the problem at all!

Comment: This is definitely a cleaner solution. @Jong-BeomKim - it would be worth looking at how much nicer this is than all the `if`s you have at the moment.

Comment: Thank you, I know the pattern matching now, but it is introduced in chapter 3 and the exercise is at the end of the chapter 2. It seems like the exercises and some examples in Real World Haskell demand more knowledge than that is already taught. As a completely beginner, I should find more organized tutorial...